# PHP primitive data type properties

Tags: php, oop, primitive

Why is it that getting a property of any PHP primitive data type does not trigger an error or warning?

Tried this on php 5.3.28:

```
$num = 1;
$str = 'hello';
$arr = array(1,2,3);
$nada = null;

$num->key1;
$str->key2;
$arr->key3;
$nada->key4;
```

No errors or warnings were triggered.

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting` enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have any error reporting enabled. When I run your code I see this:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/5BSpSI/prog.php on line 8
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/5BSpSI/prog.php on line 9
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/5BSpSI/prog.php on line 10
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/5BSpSI/prog.php on line 11
```

Try running the code again, but add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` as the first line

Comment: Not sure what is my current `error_reporting` level but setting it to `E_ALL` did show the notices. Thanks.